# Use the foreach for properties of class

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I'm writing an function to update a row in table (SQLite). At one time I only need to update certain columns of that row.

My Video class (and table) has these properties (and columns):
  Id, Name, Lyric, Cover,Gendre, Url. ( they're all string)

Now, for example, I need to update the lyric and cover of 1 row in table , I'm using this code:

```
string id = // still keep the old id, this's the PK of table;
string lyric = //get new lyric;
string cover = // get new cover;
Video item = new Video(){Id = id, Lyric = lyric, Cover = cover};
SQLiteAccess.EditVideoInfo(item);
```

Here's the EditVideoInfo

```
public static void EditVideoInfo(Video item)
    {
        var conn = new SQLiteConnection(mypath);
        using (conn)
        {
            var list = conn.Query<Video>("SELECT * FROM Video WHERE Id =?", item.Id);
            if (list.Count >0)
            {
                var editItem = list.First();  // -> Get the item need to updated
                /// Here's where I'm stuck
                conn.Update(editItem);                    
            }
        }
    }
```

So how can I read "foreach" each property of the new item and update to the old item's property if that property isn't null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below.

```
var props = typeof(Video).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.GetProperty|BindingFlags.SetProperty);

foreach (var prop in props) {
    var propVal = prop.GetValue(item, null);
    if (propVal != null)
        prop.SetValue(editItem, propVal, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to get all the properties of the Video item (take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx) but the solution would be slow and messy. Just write the test and update code for each property.

Answer (score 0):

My first approach to do this is to create a [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Dictionary<string, string> _properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
_properties["id"] = "myID"
_properties["lyric"] = "some other string"
```

and then you can iterate through it with a foreach

```
foreach (var prop in _properties)
{
    // do something with prop
}
```